# No module named ‘xgboost’ when using pickle

Tags: python, pickle, xgboost, streamlit

I am trying to deploy a xgboost classifier using streamlit. I have the model trained in a jupyter notebook file in a different folder. in the folder that has the streamlit python script, i have installed venv and im running the app through the virtual environment. streamlit works perfectly but when I try to predict using the loaded pickle file, i get an error ‘no module named xgboost’ in it. so i did install xgboost inside the virtual environment, and when i try to run again i get the error ‘super object has no attribute get_params’.

[image: error]

and the code used to import the pickled model

```
data = np.array(inputs)
ser = pd.Series(data)
with open(‘xgb_classifier_model.pickle’,‘rb’) as modelFile:
model = pickle.load(modelFile)
prediction = model.predict(ser.to_frame().transpose())
```

my first question is - do i necessarily need to install xgboost and import it in the main app.py script? (ive used the trained model in a jupyter notebook, different than the one in which it was trained, by using pickle and it ran perfectly)
my second question is - even if i install xgboost, i get the new error. is there a way to fix it?

any help would be really appreciated. i have attached the github repo link - GitHub - rohithandique/maverick-web-app

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

The error appears because the version of xgboost with which the model was trained is different from the version with which the model is deployed (after being loaded through pickle).
The google colab notebook I was working with had the xgboost version 0.9.0 whereas the version I was using in my PC is 1.3.3. Because of the differences the error popped up. I solved it my downloading the notebook and training the model on my own PC using Jupyter where I installed the 1.3.3 version of xgboost.

A bit more in detail -
Colab had version 0.9.0
Anaconda had version 1.3.3 (installed through conda)
I created a new virtual environment using venv and installed through pip (pip install xgboost==1.3.3)